# Angular ui bootstrap - Not able to inject resolve function

Tags: jquery, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap, angular-ui-bootstrap, angular-ui

I have a button on click of that i have to open a popup. This is my configuration for opening modal :

```
var uibModalInstance = $uibModal.open({
              animation: true,
              ariaLabelledBy: 'modal-title',
              ariaDescribedBy: 'modal-body',
              controller: 'lsResultPopCtrl',
              templateUrl: 'template.html',
              windowTemplateUrl: 'template.html',
              size: size,
              resolve: {
                 items: function(){
                    return $scope.items;
                }
              }
            });
```

Controller code :

```
app.controller('lsResultPopCtrl', function ($scope, $uibModal, items) {
```

This code gives me error :

```
Error: [$injector:unpr] Unknown provider: itemsProvider <- items <- lsResultPopCtrl
```

I am following this example : https://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/

Edit :

In chrome debugger I can see items array in `lsResultPopCtrl` is loaded with the data, but pop up doesn't show up and i get the error.

Comment: What does your code look like? You need that in the question. It's clear that you aren't actually using the demo word for word (the example one doesn't use $scope for instance).

Comment: Modal configurations are generated from a different function, so i included the final configuration object.

Comment: can you make a plunker ?

Answer (score 0):

The dependency you should be injecting into your controller is `$uibModalInstance`, not `$uibModal`. Change that, and it will work:

```
app.controller('lsResultPopCtrl', ['$scope', '$uibModalInstance', 'items', function ($scope, $uibModalInstance, items) {
...
}]);
```

Comment: I was not using $uibModal, I have removed it still same error.

Comment: You don't understand..., you MUST inject $uibModalInstance or the resolve will not create your variable as a dependency. You must define your controller exactly as I have described

Comment: Getting `Error: [$injector:unpr] Unknown provider: $uibModalInstanceProvider <- $uibModalInstance <- lsResultPopCtrl`,                  angular js - **v1.6.2**
angular bootstrap ui - **v2.5.0**

Comment: @Naveen Create a plunk which would surely help people answer your question.